# Grails: Pain of adding multiple child elements to a parent domain object

Tags: hibernate, jpa, grails, orm, grails-orm

I am relatively new to Grails/GORM and I have very less exposure to hibernate before this.

I am trying to map child objects to parent object in grails. I have multiple child objects to map. Child objects already exist in the database.

```
class Parent {
    static hasMany = [children: Child]
}

class Child {
    String name
}
```

I have tried the following steps,

```
def parentId = <a valid parent domain id>
def parent = Parent.get(parentId)
def children = Children.getAll([list of valid children ids])
```

I tried the `addTo*` with a list of child objects and it did not work.

```
parent.addToChildren(children)
```

It mapped only the first element from the list.

I also tried the following snippet, it did not work either.

```
parent.children += children
parent.save(flush:true)
```

I wasn't able to find a way to do this without using a loop. I believe that I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `children.each { parent.addToChildren(it) }`

The `addTo` only accepts a single instance, not a list. So iterate the list and add the individual instances.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. Actually, I ended up doing the same. But I was just curious to know if there is anything I could use without iterating the children list.